# Does Hibernate allow getdate()?

Tags: java, sql-server, hql

Currently I'm working on to get the value (verifyCount) for the current day so, in my query for SQL Server is like below

```
select verifyCount from VerifyUser where idNo = 'ABC1234'
and cast(createdDatetime as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date)
```

and in my Hibernate function, I'm using below query

```
public Integer doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
  String query = "SELECT vu .verifyCount FROM VerifyUser vu "
                + "WHERE vu .idNo= '"+ idNo+ "'"
                + "AND cast(pl.createdDatetime as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date)";

  Query q = session.createQuery(query);
  return (Integer) q.uniqueResult();
}
```

But I hit error as below

```
2020-06-02 07:02:28.018 [WebContainer : 0] ERROR k.c.m.b.w.AbstractGeneralErrorRequestListener 
  [n/a] - null
  java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at org.hibernate.dialect.function.CastFunction.render(CastFunction.java:56)
  at org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator.endFunctionTemplate(SqlGenerator.java:214)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.methodCall(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2325)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.simpleExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2699)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.expr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:1465)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.binaryComparisonExpression(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2940)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.comparisonExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:1280)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.booleanExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:910)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.booleanOp(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2858)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.booleanExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:890)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.whereExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:768)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectStatement(SqlGeneratorBase.java:191)
  at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.statement(SqlGeneratorBase.java:119)
  at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.generate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:240)
  at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:207)
  at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
  at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
  at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
  at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
  at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
  at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(HibernateTemplate.java:1387)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2575.createQuery(Unknown Source)
```

I suspect the `CAST` or `getdate()` function cannot be used in HQL query.

Really appreciate if there is any idea or solution.

Answer (score 0):

HQL uses `current_date()` to get the current date. 
You could try replacing `getdate()` with `current_date()` and check if it resolves the null pointer issue.

Comment: I've tried replacing with current_date(). Still throwing null pointer.

Comment: Try using convert instead of cast and also if you are using sql server 2005, date is not a supported data type. will need to go with datetime.
when comparing dates we need to ensure that we only check the date part and not the time, so best to convert to varchar and then compare.
```select verifyCount from VerifyUser where idNo = 'ABC1234' and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),createdDatetime,111) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),111)```

Comment: Issue resolved. I'm replace the `createQuery` with `createSQLQeury`. Thanks you!